# Yii : How to change default path of render function?

Tags: php, yii

In Yii when you using render in a widget or controller, you only need to give the file name (without .php) as a parameter, like this :

```
$this->render('forum', array('data'=>$data));
```

For example when I using this function in Class extends CWidget, Yii will try to find forum.php inside /protected/components/views

How can I change this default path to some other where ? for all my widget class (all class extends CWidget) ?  and what if I only want to change the path for some of my widget  ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the **getViewPath** method of the **CWidget** class

eg:-

```
class CMyWidget extends CWidget{

// Returns the directory containing the view files for this widget.

public function getViewPath($checkTheme=false){

// this method does the task of finding the view files containing directory.
// so override it

}

// This method will look for the view under the widget's  getViewPath viewPath.
public function getViewFile($viewName)
    {
// override it
}

    }
```

And finally when creating widgets you will have to extend the **CMyWidget** class instead of **CWidget**

Comment: Can I put getViewPath() method in the widgets I created ?
or should I make a setViewPath() method to change the setting ?

Comment: Yes you can override the getViewPath() in the widget you created but if you have to create many widgets then you will have to override the same in each widget. That would be problematic I think

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do a `$this->render('//path/forum', array('data'=>$data));`, where the `//` points to the main view directory, usually `protected/views`.

You can also use an aliased path with dot notation:

```
$this->render('application.myviews.test'); // would render protected/myviews/test.php
$this->render('webroot.test'); // would render htdocs/test.php
```

Comment: How about my view file is outside protected/views ??